# Java low FPS on PC comparing to laptop

Tags: java, frame-rate

I've just started developing simple 2D game in Java. I splitted update from draw methods. Update refreshes at specific speed of 60fps while drawing is as fast as possible. When I wrote simple FPS counter of draw and send this to friends I discovered that on laptops it has at least 200fps when on PCs it has maximum of 35. I wonder what it may be caused by. Here is Base class:

```
public class Base{

public static boolean isGameRunning;
private static Draw d;
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    isGameRunning = true;
    Game g = new Game();
    d = new Draw(g);
    Thread draw = new Thread(d);
    Thread update = new Thread(new Update(g));
    GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice gd = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    JFrame window = new JFrame();

    setWindow(window);
    window.setContentPane(d);
    gd.setFullScreenWindow(window);
    g.initialize();
    draw.start();
    update.start();
}
private static void setWindow(JFrame window)
{
    window.setUndecorated(true);
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}}
```

And a Draw class here:

```
package basic;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import main.Game;

class Draw extends JPanel implements Runnable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Game g;
    public Color bgColor = Color.BLACK;

    Draw(Game g)
    {
        this.g = g;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        paintComponent(getGraphics());
        while(Base.isGameRunning)
        {
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics graph)
    {
        try
        {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graph;
            g2d.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g2d.setColor(bgColor);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g.draw(g2d);
        }catch(NullPointerException e)
        {

        }
    }

 }
```

[EDIT] Here is an update class:

```
package basic;
import main.Game;
class Update implements Runnable{
private final int FPS = 60;
private long targetTime = 1000/FPS;
//private Game g;

//Update(Game g)
//{
    //this.g = g;
//}
public void run()
{
    long start, elapsed, wait;
    while(Base.isGameRunning)
    {
        start = System.nanoTime();
        //g.update();
        elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;
        wait = targetTime - elapsed / 1000000;

        try 
        {
            Thread.sleep(wait);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Some improvement can be done. I tried to change the code as you didn't provide the Update class.

```
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/**
 *
 * @author Pasban
 */
public class Base {

    public static boolean isGameRunning;
    private static Draw d;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        isGameRunning = true;
        d = new Draw();
        Thread draw = new Thread(d);
        GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice gd = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
        JFrame window = new JFrame();

        setWindow(window);
        window.setContentPane(d);
        gd.setFullScreenWindow(window);
        //g.initialize();
        draw.start();
    }

    private static void setWindow(JFrame window) {
        window.setUndecorated(true);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

And

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 *
 * @author Pasban
 */
class Draw extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public Color bgColor = Color.BLACK;
    private long timer;
    private long lastTime;
    private int FPS;
    private int FPSLast;

    public void run() {
        paintComponent(getGraphics());

        this.timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        this.lastTime = 0;
        this.FPS = 0;
        this.FPSLast = 0;
        while (Base.isGameRunning) {
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics graph) {
        try {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graph;
            //g2d.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g2d.setColor(bgColor);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            //g.draw(g2d);
            g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            long dist = System.currentTimeMillis() - this.timer;
            if (dist - this.lastTime > 1000) {
                this.lastTime = dist;
                this.FPSLast = this.FPS;
                this.FPS = 0;
            }
            this.FPS++;
            g2d.drawString(dist + "ms / " + this.FPSLast + "fps", 50, 50);

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

currently the FPS in my old PC is 103 by the above codes. The main change I applied is on this line:

```
//g2d.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
```

By enabling this line, the FPS downwards to 70FPS which means this line itself uses 50+FPS. However, let it be disables as you fill the drawing rect after this command, and again that means you use your CPU and FPS for no reason and it will have no effect on your drawing canvas.

One more improvement can be fixing your FPS by applying Thread.sleep(time) if it is beyond  60+FPS. Or you can ignore repaint method within your while (Base.isGameRunning) when it is too early to repaint.

Comment: I didn't help :/ I have added Update. And have you got any idea why on laptops it seems to work properly?

Comment: I think you need to check if your graphic card is the same as your friend's. If you compare the device features, you will find the reason. I don't have any external GraphicCard but, when I had one, the graphical processes were running much more faster. It is obvious that instead of accessing your main RAM, it access to its own ram which it is faster. That is what I think. Maybe someone else has better explanation.